# Can't sweep from Paper wallet. Unsupported Format

Tags: etherscan, private-key, paper-wallets

I have an Ethereum paper wallet from 2 years ago. I am trying to sweep the paper wallet using Coinomi. The app states that the format of the private key is unsupported. The public key works properly on Etherscan but I am unable to use the private key.

Comment: What app did you use to generate the paper wallet?

Comment: I used a BelcoATM.

Comment: I've never heard of that wallet, perhaps the private key is in bitcoin wallet format. (wif)

Comment: I tried to convert from WIF to private key but the program said that it's in invalid base 58 encoding.

Comment: If it is a hexadecimal string you may try with Metamask, MyEtherWallet or MyCrypt they support that kind of private keys.

Comment: Where do i enter the private key in myetherwallet?

Comment: This method is not recommended because it is not as secure as using a hardware wallet or similar, so make sure your computer and browser are secure, disable plugins you do not trust, etc.
In their home page select "Access My Wallet", then "Access By Software", in the popup select "Private Key".